# What does "1 line >ed 1 time" mean in VIM?

Tags: vim

Lately I have been encountering a problem in VIM.

I use the shortcut >> (hold shift, press the period key twice) to indent a line. Sometimes I must be hitting something wrong because this shortcut stops working until I restart VIM.

Every time I try to indent with the shortcut it says "1 line >ed 1 time" instead of indenting. Or, if I have 3 lines selected and try to indent them all it will say: "3 lines >ed 1 time".

How do I fix this and restore the shortcut?

Thanks!

Comment: I could reproduced this behavior; here it only appears while indenting a visually marked block (and never on the first indent). I have no solution for this so far ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea, why your shortcut is not working, or what's the wrong key that you have pressed.

Regarding your `1 line >ed 1 time` message: What you're doing is to shift a number of lines to the right. Vim is just notifying you about what was done, which is: One line is right-shifted one time. The `>` here is the right shift operator and `>ed` is just short for "shifted". If you do the opposite it says `<ed`, which is shifted to the left.

You can find more details in vim's help with: `:help >`

Answer (score 0):

When a section is marked (visually marked) one > is sufficiant. The 2nd > should start another indentation, but since now nothing is marked it waits for another >.

More than this, I couldn't reproduce any error. (As it was mentioned by frosch03, the msg is just the normal response)

Answer (score -1):

**ed** was an (well, probably still is) old editor, but I doubt that is what Vim is telling you. I cannot reproduce the message you're getting, nor find anything in the documentation regarding it.

Does this happen also when you're using a ***clean* Vim** (when you start it without vimrc with ***vim/gvim -u none***)? If so, could you paste your vimrc if it's not too big somewhere (one of those paste sites should do nicely), so we can take a look to see is there any weird combo inside causing that behaviour.

Apart from that, not much advice I can offer regarding the given data :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the message doesn't have anything to do with `ed` the editor.

Comment: It's not about the `ed` editor. `>` means "shift". `>ed` means "shifted".